# Is it a good idea to use images local URL in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, dom, innerhtml

I want to make a list of projects and I made an array and using `.map()` method to display them, and I'm adding that list in the HTML element using `.insertAdjacentHTML()` method.

While inspecting the elements I can see the image path is coming fine but image is not showing in UI. What would be the reason of it?

```
const projectData = [
    {
        id: 01,
        title: "Project 1",
        url: "https://react-projects-1/",
        imageUrl: "src/img/projects/project-1.png", //is it wrong using like this
        description: "This is project 1 desc",
    },
    {
        id: 02,
        title: "Project 2",
        url: "https://react-projects-2/",
        imageUrl: "src/img/projects/project-2.png", //is it wrong using like this
        description: "This is project 2 desc",
    },
];
```

Mapping them and using the HTML:-

```
const projectHTML = projectData.map((el) => {
    return `<div class="row align-items-center project_row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-12 order-md-2">
                    <a href="${el.url}" class="thumb">
                        <img
                            src="${el.imageUrl}"
                            class="w-100"
                            alt="${el.title}"
                            target="_blank"
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-12 order-md-1 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                    <h3><span>${el.id}.</span>${el.title}</h3>
                    <p>
                        ${el.description}
                    </p>
                    <ul class="buildTech">
                        <li><i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i> React</li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="${el.url}" class="btn" target="_blank">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>`;
});

workWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", projectHTML);
```

[image]

Inspect:-

[image]

Comment: The issue isn't that it's in an array. It's that the path is wrong. What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Im using the same path hard coded in HTML, then image is coming fine

Comment: If I had to guess, you need to remove the `src/`. I see people do this often. Either way, your path is wrong in one way or another. Nothing to do with js.

Comment: Im using parcel, and I get some different compiled type url of images when I use it in HTML file, maybe that's why its happening cuz it's coming from a js file, what do you think ?

Comment: See this, I used simeple `<img src="src/img/project-thumbnails/project-1.png" alt="">` in html https://prnt.sc/ct_eee3CppHa